# Changing properties of a keyframe

Tags: animation, keyframes

Often I'll try changing the position of an object or whatever it may be, and forget to apply the keyframe, then the timeline moves, I quit the program, I start to render, or whatever, and either the keyframe before the change or the saved keyframe on that frame takes over and I loose all my work. Autosave isn't reliable so is there a way to have the keyframe auto-update to changes made to the properties it defines?

Answer (score 5):

You can enable auto keyframing on the timeline by pressing the red button:
[image]

more info on the [manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/animation/editors/timeline.html?highlight=timeline#keyframe-control)

Comment: Thank you, I was assuming that it would record multiple frames of data, which I know it can do, but I have never used it. Thanks allot :)